# Арап и мавр

Tags: этимология

Насколько я знаю, раньше на Руси был такой парадокс: арапами называли негров, а арабов - маврами. Насчет мавров я еще могу предположить, что от названия страны Мавритании, но почему - арапы? Да еще и через П, а не Б. В принципе, спутать араба и негра достаточно сложно.
Поэтому интересно было бы узнать, откуда взялись эти названия - арап и мавр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Негр - это "черный" по-латински, мавр - тоже самое, но по-гречески (так что Мавритания от мавров, а не наоборот). Арап - это от "араба", до юпохи Великих геогрфических открытий все негры в Европу, в том числе и в Россию попадали через арабов. Что же касается "араба и негра невозможно перепутать", так индейцы на индийцев тоже совсем не похожи, но Колумб их тем не менее перепутал.

Comment: Думаю, что Колумб не слишком хорошо знал, как выглядят индийцы - в те времена еще индийские фильмы не были известны))))))

Comment: @Марк Из. Я не согласен, что АРАП  это от АРАБа, - "все негры  в Европу, в том числе и в Россию, попадали через арабов." Смотрите мой ответ на этот вопрос ниже.

Comment: > не согласен, что АРАП это от АРАБа,  
  
Да вроде как нет причин сомневаться...

Answer (score 1):

Слово Мавр производное от слова Варвар (чужестранец) Бербер . Как бы помягче ...Мавр- это кадровый военный ,с детства  держащий(боевое - не игрушечное!)  оружие в руках ("Берберы-свободные мужчины ")У нас мальчик- Суворовец, а в Афганистане -мальчик с Калашниковым в руках.Как правило Мавр - младший в семье , лишенный наследства . Помните Айвенго ? Знаменитое ДЕСДЕЧАДО ? Киношники ,что с них взять  . На самом деле Дамуазо .  Медленно, мы приближаемся к сложному, слову- Арап.С одной стороны это ПАЖ . Арабское письмо . Переводчик "гугл "  перевёл слово "АРАП"как негр , но дал и ещё один вариант перевода " السمرة"- ТАН .ТАН-
(шотланд. thane - дворянин). В древней Англии так назывались лица, составлявшие свиту князя. В Шотландии до конца XV столетия - вожди кланов.
Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка.- Чудинов А.Н., 1910.

ТАН
шотланд. thane, англ.-сакс. thegen, tnegn, then, рыцарь, дворянин. В древней Англии непосредственный вассал короля.
Объяснение 25000 иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русский язык, с означением их корней.- Михельсон А.Д., 1865. Вот как то так.Вывод: МАВР это вояка , Арап- вассал (не простой слуга !!!). Паж ,рында ,при Господине.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу МАВР/НЕГР согласен с [[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7). Но, что касается АРАПа, то я не думаю, что от АРАБа. Арапами называли, например, эфиопов (*Арап Петра Великого, И.П. Ганнибал - предок Пушкина*), а они не арабы (по антропологическим признакам). АРАП это применительно к негроидной расе. На иврите **עָרַף** *араф*=*арап* (буква пей читается двояко - как Ф и П) означает **обезглавить**, **отсечь голову**. Смотрите **ИРИС-словарь д-ра Баруха Подольского** [link text](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php), там есть поиск по транскрипции. Профессия палача была в Европе одной из наиболее презренных профессий, и на эту должность (для казни на плахе) специально нанимались чернокожие африканцы.

Comment: @следопыт, а можно ссылку про чернокожих палачей? Заранее благодарю

Comment:   @Innak. К сожалению, ссылочки нет. Но, что профессия палача считалась в Европе весьма презренной, я знаю точно. И, что на эту должность нанимали чернокожих суть моё предположение. А в Древнем Египте функции исполнителей наказаний и пыток выполняли эфиопы (кушиты) из племени маджаев.

Comment: @следопыт. Спасибо

Comment: Я еще раз не понимаю, с какого боку тут иврит?!

Answer (score 0):

В принципе Марк Из все сказал (если не придираться к деталям).
Могу только уточнить, что слово "арап" пришло из турецкого, где означает именно араба, но в силу недостаточного знакомства с самим понятием (кто до Петра на Руси негров видел и от арабов отличал?) изменило в русском значение.

*Возможно сказалось и то, что по библейским представлением никаких "негров" и нет вовсе. Библия говорит о трех расах: потомках Сима, Хама и Яфета. "Хамиты"  почти исчезли в современном мире (к ним относили, в частности доарабское население севера Африки), арабы - семиты, белые - яфетиды. Типа того: "Какие еще негры? Если из Африки, значит арабы - только черные".*

А араб - это уже от самих арабов - посредством европейских.

//===
"Мавритания" произошла от "мавров", не наоборот. Значение слова уже приводилось - "черный" на греческом.

Answer (score 0):

Мар

мар I I. "солнечный зной; сухая мгла; сон", ма́рит "(солнце) печет, особенно при туманном, душном воздухе", марь ж. "туман; возрастающий зной", ма́рный "знойный, теплый, мутный", **жирный текст**сюда же мо́ра "темнота, туман",**жирный текст** момра́ – то же (Бернекер), болг. мараня́ "душный давящий зной", ма́рен "тепловатый", сербохорв. о̏-мара "духота", в.-луж. womara "полусон, обморок". Сюда же мре́ю "отсвечиваю". Родственно греч. ἀμαρύσσω (*ἀμαρύκι̯ω) "сверкаю", ἀμαρυγή "блеск, сверкание", μαρμάρεος "блистающий, сверкающий", μαρμαίρω "блистать, сверкать, гореть, как жар", μαῖρα (*μαρι̯α) "Сириус", др.-инд. márīciṣ, mаrīсī ж. "луч", marīcikā "мираж"; см. Сольмсен, Jagić-Festschrift 579 и сл.; Бернекер 2, 21 и сл.; Петерссон, Från Filol. Fören. Lund 4, 122. Ср. ма́рево. II II. "холм; насыпь; могильный холм", ю.-вост. Из морд. м. mаr "куча, могильный холм" (см. Паасонен, Мordw. Chrest. 93; Равила, RS 11, 160). Ср. мишар. mаr "холм" (Радлов 4, 2025). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Неплохие такие слова к описанию Африки(МАВРИТАНИИ).

латынь
MAURUS-черный
morulus, a, um тёмный, чёрный PI (v. /.).

Марать

марать мара́ть мара́ю, укр. мара́ти, польск. marać, в.-луж. marać, mórać "мазать", н.-луж. maraś, moraś "болтать, говорить пошлости". Родственно греч. μορύσσω "пачкаю, мараю, черню" (Сольмсен, Jagić-Festschrift 576 и сл.; Бернекер 2, 18; Траутман, ВSW 169)